# How to remove not matching values from sub-document from MongoDB collection?

Tags: mongodb, dictionary, document

I have a the below document in my one of the mongoDB collection.

```
{"key":"CarName","value":{"default":"Unknown","MyCar":"TNK1234","YourCar":"TNW2342"}}
```

In this document, I only want to keep the **"MyCar"** item in the **value** sub-document.

I have tried

```
db.mycollection.update({{"key":"CarName"},{value.MyCar:0}},{$pull:{value.MyCar:0}});
```

But the entire document is getting deleted. Not sure of the syntax.

I would like the document to look like

> {'key': 'CarName',  'value': {'TNK1234': 'My Car'}}

After some suggestions on the comments

I tried

```
db.mycollection.update({"key":"CarName"},{$unset:{"value.default:"","value.YourCar":""}});
```

which works

But in the event if I have multiple fields to unset, I will have to mention all the fields that I want to remove so I am looking for alternatives.

Comment: The field `value` is _not_ an array type - it is sub-document.

Comment: Thanks @prasad_, I have changed my question accordingly. Any suggestions for solution?

Comment: Try using the [$unset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) update operator.

Comment: If I have to use $unset, I should mention all the sub-document keys which I intend to remove. I don't find a way to mention only the sub-document keys which I intend to keep.

Comment: The documentation says: _"To specify a <field> in an embedded document or in an array, use dot notation."_

Comment: yes, I specified the field using dot notation, but I have to specify multiple fields. Imagine if I have 100 fields and I want to remove 98 fields except 2

Comment: If you have lot of fields to _unset_ then you have to use some other approach. MongoDB version 4.2+ versions support Aggregation pipeline for the _update_; you can use it. See [Updates with Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/index.html).

Comment: You don't need multiple statements to unset for multiple fields. You can specify multiple fields within one update statement. See the documentation once again; it is explained there.

Comment: Yes my bad, I still have to type all the fields that I want to remove. I should look into aggregation pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MongoDB 4.2, you can specify a pipeline to handle the update.  One way to accomplish that is:

- convert the object to an array of key-value pair
- filter the array, keeping only the key you want
- convert the array back to an object
- store the value back in the original field

```
db.mycollection.update({"key":"CarName"},
                       [{$set: {
                          value: {
                            $arrayToObject: {
                              $filter: {
                                        input: {$objectToArray: "$value"},
                                        cond: {$eq: ["$$this.k","MyCar"]}
                              }
                            }
                          }
                       }}]
)
```

Mongo playground doesn't support update, but this demonstrates what that pipeline stage would do: [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uj7bGb95UU7)

Comment: Thanks @Joe for the answer and the explanation , I am new to MongoDB, will study how your answer works.